# GetAddrInfo fails with subdomains

Tags: c++, winsock, getaddrinfo

I was wondering if you knew why GetAddrInfo fails with subdomains? Example: `www.support.hostgator.com`

```
Return value from WSAGetLastError() is 11001
No such host is known
```

I looked around on MSDN and didn't find anything about how to handle this.

Here is the simplified problem:

```
#include <string>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
int main(){

    std::wstring Domain = L"www.support.hostgator.com";
    std::wstring Port = L"443";

    WSADATA WsaData{0};
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &WsaData);

    addrinfoW hints{ 0 }, *results = nullptr;
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

    if (GetAddrInfoW(Domain.c_str(), Port.c_str(), &hints, &results)) {
        return WSAGetLastError();
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Just to check the obvious, but you _did_ test the hostname/port outside your program? That said, you should simplify your example code. It's not yet a [mcve]

Comment: Yeah outside my program it works perfectly fine (Used chrome browser) and yeah I simplify it.

Comment: Ideally, you should distill your problem down to just a `main()` function. Nobody can just take your `int Adaptify::Connect(LPWSTR Domain, LPWSTR Port` and compile that. (It's also a useful technique to debug issues yourself: when simplifying a presumed problem, cutting out " irrelevant" code may suddenly solve the problem.)

Comment: @MSalters Thanks for the tip, that will actually help down the road. I have updated the post to literally the bare minimum to recreate the problem.

Comment: Have you gotten your program to work with *any* host name?

Comment: @Andrew Henel yeah every other domain like Google.com works perfectly fine.

Comment: That program cannot produce that output.

Comment: [Works for me in Visual Studio 2012, after adding proper output and C++03-ing it](http://rextester.com/BQUK97607).

Comment: I have discovered it failed with the www. But once I removed it, it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: @TrevinCorkery: `www.` is not magic. You need an actual DNS entry for `www.`. There's no reason to assume you can blindly prefix `www.` and have things still work the same.

Comment: @MSalters Yeah that was my own ignorance. I am so using to applying www. to evertthing I type in on the internet. (I'm about to look up the difference)

Comment: @TrevinCorkery: There's no real difference, that's the whole point! `example.com` and `www.example.com` are both syntactically valid DNS names which may or may not exist, and their existence is unrelated.

Comment: Browsers may try adding or removing `www.` and `.com` on their own.